# babylon.js how to get access to a mesh outside of it's function

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

I just cant get access to the babylon mesh.
Everytime I try to run the code I get this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlt4u.png).

I've tried it with two different approaches:

**Example 1:**

```
var carTest;
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene, function(object) {
        carTest = object[0];
    });
carTest.position.x = 10;
```

**Example 2:**

```
var carTest = BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene);
carTest.position.x = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the synchron method with callback function you could use the async function if you know the concept of async / await.

Example:

```
const data = await SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene);
const carMeshes = data.meshes;
```

If you know there is only one with children you could access [0] otherwise you may need to merger the meshes. Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your example 2, 
The BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh return `Nullable<ISceneLoaderPlugin | ISceneLoaderPluginAsync>`, and both of them do not have property name as position.
Thus, carTest.position would be undefined.

```
carTest.position.x = 10 => undefined.x = 10;
```

will throw error.

In your first example, 
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh is a synchronized function, although there is another function name ImportMeshAsync in BABYLON.SceneLoader...

I have not used BABYLON before.
But basically, according to [BABYLON API](https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.sceneloader#importmesh), the difference between ImportMesh and ImportMeshAsync is the returned type.

so,

**[Improvement]**

move `carTest.position.x = 10;` in your onSuccess callback.

```
BABYLON
  .SceneLoader
  .ImportMesh("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene, function(object) {
        carTest = object[0];
        carTest.position.x = 10;
    });
```

Comment: Exactly this is the thing i want to avoid.
The `carTest.position.x = 10;` has to be outside.

Comment: Could you explain why you want `carTest.position.x = 10;` to be outside? Do you need it to run before `BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh` ?

Comment: The car needs to move based on real time data wich is coming from different scripts. The date is coming in form of x and y coordinates. In best case the `carTest.position.x = 10;` has to be in a different script as well.
It doesn't need to run before `BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh`.

Answer (score 0):

When call SceneLoader, the carTest object only are set when return the onlyne (function), then the object are not ready in the next line (carTest do not exist at this time).

You need await to use carTest object when SceneLoader are finish.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is; you need to wait until your mesh is loaded before you can start doing stuff with it. A simple way to do this is just wait a couple of seconds:

```
var carTest;
BABYLON
    .SceneLoader
    .ImportMesh("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene, function(object) {
        carTest = object[0];
    });

function moveCar(){
    carTest.position.x = 10;
}

setTimeout(moveCar,2000);
```

The longer answer is that Javascript is Asynchronous, which means it doesn't wait for an instruction to finish before moving onto the next. In your examples it starts loading car.obj but before it's finished it moves onto the next instruction and starts trying to set the position - which it can't do because it's not finished loading yet, hence the error.

My 'setTimeout' solution is simple to understand but not very elegant. A better solution is to use the provided callback function to trigger the code which handles your mesh, as this will only run once the model is loaded.

```
var carTest;
BABYLON
    .SceneLoader
    .ImportMesh("", "assets/", "car.obj", scene, function(object) {
        carTest = object[0];
        startCar();
    });

function startCar(){
    carTest.position.x = 10;
}
```

The best solution is to properly master the asynchronous programming paradigm, learn about 'Javascript Promises' and use BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync as suggested by Thomas Wenger.