# Examples for Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

Does anybody know good examples for working Babylon.js games/applications, where I can also see the code?

I am searching for them, cause of this question: [babylon.js how to get access to a mesh outside of it's function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62018719/13618722)

I've tried to get answers from some of the Babylon-Playground examples, but these dont help that much.